# How do I add a snippet programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have some custom snippets we provide as part of our VS Code extension via key bindings and a snippets json file:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
  "mac": "cmd+shift+i",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet"
},
```

...

```
"snippets": [
  {
    "language": "xml",
    "path": "./snippets/xml.json"
  }
]
```

We would like a button to add one particular snippet to the editor at the current cursor position.

How do I programmatically I invoke the part of "editor.action.insertSnippet" *after* the user has selected the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33280) on the [vscode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/).

[jrieken](https://github.com/jrieken) responded with the following [reply](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33280#issuecomment-327412638):

> The insertSnippet-command accepts an argument which is either the name of a snippet or a snippet itself. So, either { snippet: "console.log($1)$0"} for an inline snippet or { langId: "csharp", name: "myFavSnippet" } referencing an existing snippet.

Comment: So it's been over a year now, and the docs aren't updated with that information. I tried with the `{langId: 'blah', name: 'mySnippet'}` and either I'm doing something wrong (entirely possible), or it doesn't actually support that option. Also that conversation got locked so I couldn't comment there.

Comment: @joshea As I understand it, the language identifiers need to be from this [list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers). Also, you might want to make sure _mySnippet_ is already defined. If it is not, [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/snippet-guide) might be helpful in understanding how to create it.

Comment: Yeah I have all that, and the actual `langId` I had was `javascriptreact`, which is on that list. I'll just triple check that the snippet is defined. Knowing me I probably have a typo in the name or something.

Comment: @joshea I also had no luck inserting an existing snippet programmatically using e.g. `editor.insertSnippet({ langId: "javascript", name: "module_exports" }` - though I might have the syntax wrong. It seems a string is required like the doco says. Sure, the `"editor.action.insertSnippet"` keybinding command takes those fancy `"langId"` and `"name"` args but not `editor.insertSnippet`. However, as @Mike-Lischke suggested, I managed to programmatically do it using e.g. `vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.insertSnippet", { langId: "javascript", name: "For Loop" })`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any registered command via `vscode.commands.executeCommand`. See also the [vscode namespace API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api).

Comment: Thank you, Mike. What is the command for inserting a _selected_ snippet (that does not involve the user picking one)?